# I am trying to add a right swipe gesture to uiImagepicker

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Can you show me how to do it I tried subclass into new object didn't work

Comment: Append your code please..

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? The docs of `UIImagePickerController` Important: **This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.**

Comment: I am trying to do a custom camera like snapchat no iris anim swipe left right

Comment: You can't do this with `UIImagePickerController` you will have to using the AVFoundation framework to create your entirely custom camera.

Comment: Ok how do I do it using avfoundation thanks fogmeister

Comment: That's bigger than a StackOverflow question. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html take a look here and if you get stuck on a specific problem come ad ask here.